# Angular fullstack generator add script

Tags: gulp, angular-fullstack, yo

I want to include google map js file in my angular full-stack generator project.
When I add the following line in _index.html file it gives me following error

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>
```

> vendor.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   polyfills.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   app.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I remove google map script it works fine.
Is there any other way using which i can include extra script file.

Comment: Are you aware that your line is missing **>** at the end ?

Comment: yes acutally that is my mistake in writting question.
I have ended script tag properly in code.